# Как добавлять option один раз, и не дублировать при повторном выборе города?

Tags: javascript

```
districts.forEach(dist => {
    if (dist.city_id === city_id) {
        filtred_districts.push(dist)
    }
})


//Заполняем селект
function appendOption () {

   for (var i = 0; i <= filtred_districts.length; i++) {
           var option = document.createElement("option");
           option.setAttribute("value", filtred_districts[i].name.toString());
           option.innerHTML = filtred_districts[i].name.toString();
           district_select.appendChild(option);
       }
   }

    let select_target = e.target.value

    if (select_target === "moscow") {
        appendOption()
    }

    if (select_target === "saint-petersburg") {
        appendOption()
    }
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать в переполнение стека! :)

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее что вы хотите сделать, а лучше добавьте сниппет воспроизводимого кода.

Comment: @Алексей это продолжение [вот этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485730/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Такую ошибку вижу в консоли: script.js:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at appendOption (script.js:178:62)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (script.js:188:9)

Comment: Вообщем оно работает вроде,  и option заполняется. Но, если я повторно нажимаю в фильтре на тот же город, то в фильтр районов дублируется этот option

Comment: Help ребят @Алексей